# outlook 2010 open attachment shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2010

My company upgraded me from 2007 to 2010.  I had a very easy way to open attachments in 2007 through keyboard use only.  Context menu, h, o.

This option is no longer available in 2010.

Does anyone know of a keyboard shortcut to open Outlook attachments through keyboard hotkeys as it is a very big part of my work?

I'm open to autohotkey answers.